# How to make a discord bot copy the latest message in a channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I want to create a bot that copies everything that everybody says. I tried to make a .txt file that puts everything someone says, but it gets cluttered quickly and it doesn't send the messages anyway. Any help?

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def copy(ctx):
    with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
        async for message in ctx.history(limit=1000):
            f.write(message.content + "\n")
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it send the messages?

Comment: @Chuaat weellllll





look at the code ;n;

Comment: So do you mean it's an error the messages aren't "sending"? Or do you mean I don't ctx.send them anyway?

Comment: Your code seems to be working without any errors or anything.... There isn't any sending codes or anything.... What do you need _help_ with?

Comment: So you want to send every message that already was sent again? Just for clarifications so I can help you

Comment: @Chuaat yes....

Comment: Do you want to send it immediately? Or do you want to send them after you trigger a command?

Comment: @12944qwerty i want it to send immediately -

Comment: Then why would you want to store it in a file? That just seems a bit redundant....

Comment: @12944qwerty thats.. why im here.. im trying to get better solutions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send every message again immediately after it got sent, add:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.channel.send(message.content)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

To avoid the bot also multiplying it's own message, check if the `message.author` is the bot:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
        await ctx.send(message.content)
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

You can delete the command copy if you want to.

References:

- [on_message()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message)

Comment: you might want to add 'ctx,' before the message :)

Comment: @Devalart What do you mean? That code is correct...

Comment: Just corrected it, simply adding `ctx` wouldn't have worked, as ctx was not defined.

Comment: BTW Chuaat, You can just do `if not message.author.bot:`, this will avoid all bots